# Matplotlib raise ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer in tkinter app

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a tkinter app and i want to open video and then show chart in another window.(using cv2)

If i first click on show chart button, it works fine.But when I open the file, the chart is no longer displayed when i click on show chart button(open new widow and show chart)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window, cap):
        self.window = window
        self.cap = cap

        self.frame_rate = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        self.video_length = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        self.current_frame = 0

        self.scale = tk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=self.video_length, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=400, command=self.on_scale)
        self.scale.pack()

        self.frame_label = tk.Label(window)
        self.frame_label.pack()

        self.update()

    def on_scale(self, value):
        self.current_frame = int(value)

    def update(self):
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.current_frame)
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.frame_label.img = img  # Keep a reference to the image to prevent garbage collection
            self.frame_label.config(image=img)
        self.window.after(int(1000 / self.frame_rate), self.update)

def open_file(window):
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
        player = VideoPlayer(window, cap)

def get_input_number(input):
     user_input = input.get()
     print("User input:", user_input) 

def open_new_window():
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    new_window.title("Chart Window")

    # Create a simple bar chart
    data = {'Apples': 10, 'Oranges': 15, 'Bananas': 7, 'Berries': 20}
    categories = list(data.keys())
    values = list(data.values())
    fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
    plot = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plot.bar(categories, values)

    # Embed the chart in the new window
    chart_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=new_window)
    print(categories, values, 1)
    chart_canvas.draw()
    print(categories, values, 2)
    chart_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    print(categories, values, 3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Video Player")

    side = tk.Frame(master=root, width=200, height=700)
    side.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

    main = tk.Frame(master=root, width=500, height=700)
    main.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

    open_button = tk.Button(side, text="Open Video", command=lambda: open_file(main))
    open_button.pack(pady=20)

    open_window_btn = tk.Button(side, text="Open New Window with Chart", command=open_new_window)
    open_window_btn.pack(pady=20)

    var = tk.Entry(master=side)
    var.pack()

    input_number = tk.Entry(master=side)
    input_number.pack(pady=20)

    process_btn = tk.Button(side, text="Process", command=lambda: get_input_number(input_number))
    process_btn.pack(pady=20)

    root.mainloop()
```

I get this error when i open video file and then click on show chart button(open new widow and show chart):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AlibyGAP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892
, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "a.py", line 64, in open_new_window
    chart_canvas.draw()
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 10, in dra
w
    super().draw()
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 400, in draw

    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3175, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_composit
ing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3064, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_composit
ing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1392, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 301, in draw
    artist.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 800, in draw
    textrenderer.draw_text(gc, x, y, clean_line,
  File "D:\projects\gui\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 217, in draw
_text
    x = round(x + xo + xd)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: This part of your code `x = round(x + xo + xd)` raises an exception